# How to fetch list datatype column value from cassandra in python

Tags: python, collections, cassandra, datastax-python-driver

Can anyone help with query : how to fetch list datatype column value   from cassandra in python

Answer (score 0):

Sure; let's assume we're building a simple table to hold users' favorite movies:

```
CREATE TABLE fav_movies (
    name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    movies LIST<TEXT>);
```

Assuming that someone wanted to query my favorite movies, they start by defining my name as a local variable, creating a prepared statement, and then executing it.

```
name = "Aaron"
pStatement = session.prepare("SELECT movies FROM stackoverflow.fav_movies WHERE name=?");

rows = session.execute(pStatement,(name,)).one()
```

If there is a result set returned, the movies list could be set to a local variable and iterated through to show each value:

```
if rows:
    movies = rows.movies
    
    for movie in movies:
        print(movie)
```

Running this program would produce results similar to this:

```
$ python3 queryList.py pUlOXBMyAstraDBSecretOrUserameyPHxZpka 5kHKNIuMyAstraDBTokenOrPasswordQ684
Star Wars
Blade Runner
The Martian
```

The code use above can be found in my Git repo: https://github.com/aploetz/python_scripts/blob/master/queryList.py